# array class member, with dynamically changeable length during runtime

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to make a network application. Its class blueprint is roughly like this-

```
class Node
{
    public:
    // member functions
    private:
    int nodeID;
    // other members
};

class NodeNetwork
{
    public:
    // member functions
    private:
    Node nodeArray[MAX_NODES];
    // other members
};
```

Here, the Node class will deal with each node and the NodeNetwork is used to deal with the complete network.

The actual number of nodes in `nodeArray` can vary from 0 to MAX_NODES during runtime, i.e., it may not always be `MAX_NODES`, the number of nodes can be increased or decreased during runtime. Moreover, when the program starts the number will always be 0, after that it will start increasing.

I am using `Node nodeArray[MAX_NODES];`, but I think it's a serious wastage of space as not always I will have `MAX_NODES` nodes at runtime. So I am looking for ways to optimize it. I want it so that it starts with a zero-length array, but the size can be increased or decreased subjected to the above constraints based on the nodes added or removed at runtime. I researched on the internet but did not find any concrete answer.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::vector< Node > nodeArray;`

Comment: You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of array. For example, `std::vector<Node> nodeArray;`.

Comment: Any time you need a dynamic array in c++ a vector usually should be your first choice.

Comment: @RichardCritten, thanks for your suggestions. I forgot to mention that the application is for embedded devices, so we are not allowed to use STL, I already knew about vector, but can't use it. Sorry, it's my mistake that I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @AnoopRana, same as above

Comment: @drescherjm, same as above

Comment: @ankitbansal Ok so you can close this question by accepting whichever answer you find most suitable to your current question and can ask a separate question specifically for embedded devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamically array allocation for this purpose:

```
int* arr = new int[5];
```

..and anytime you wish to change the number of elements:

```
int size = 5;
int* arr = new int[size] {};

int* new_arr = new int[size + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    new_arr[i] = arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
arr = new_arr;

// Now arr has a storage capacity of 6 elements
```

..so for your case you can write:

```
Node* nodeArray = nullptr; // nullptr == null pointer
```

But this can take a lot of time for huge arrays.

So preferably, you can use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vec.push_back(6); //Insert a new element

    std::cout << vec[0]; // Accessing an element is the same as an array
}
```

..so for your case:

```
// {} is just for initialization, not exactly mandatory
std::vector<Node> nodeArray{};
```

Comment: There is just about no use case for using `new T[n]` that can't be replaced by `std::vector<T>(n)` or `std::make_unique<T[]>(n)`. It is basically always an error to recommend `new` as the solution to anything (except maybe placement `new`).

Comment: I expect the only reason for recommendation is for academic reasons where the person asking is not permitted to use a vector or smart pointers.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I forgot to mention that the application is for embedded devices, so we are not allowed to use STL, I already knew about vector, but can't use it. Sorry, it's my mistake that I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of array. That is, you can make the **data member** `nodeArray` to be a `std::vector<Node>` as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
class Node
{
    public:
       //constructor for initializing nodeID data member 
       Node(int pnodeID): nodeID(pnodeID)
       {
           
       }
       //getter for nodeId
       int getId() const 
       {
           return nodeID;
       }
    private:
       //always initialize built in type in local/block scope so that they don't have indeterminate value
       int nodeID = 0; 
    // other members
};

class NodeNetwork
{
    public:
    
        // member function to add Node 
        void addNode(const Node& n)
        {
            nodeArray.push_back(n);
        }
        //member function to print out the current nodes 
        void display() const
        {
            std::cout<<"Network has the following nodes: "<<std::endl;
            for(const Node& elem: nodeArray)
            {
                std::cout<<elem.getId()<<std::endl;
                
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Node> nodeArray; //used std::vector instead of array
    // other members
};
int main()
{
    //create Node objects 
    Node node1{1};
    Node node2{2};
    Node node3{3};
    
    NodeNetwork network1;
    
    //add node1 into the network1's nodeArray data member 
    network1.addNode(node1);
    
    //add node2 into the network1's nodeArray data member 
    network1.addNode(node2);

    //display all nodes into network1 
    network1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/kk4vXSTjN) we have added elements into the `nodeArray` data member by using `std::vector::push_back` member function.

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/kk4vXSTjN):

```
Network has the following nodes: 
1
2
```